# ESP8266 webserver http header trouble with Content-Encoding

Tags: http, gzip, esp8266

I am stuck with a gzip header issue. I have ARduino Due + ESP8266 + SD card shield. I am also using https://github.com/itead/ITEADLIB_Arduino_WeeESP8266/tree/develop There is an html file that is gzipped and saved on an SD card. Basic webserver operations are working. My issue is with http headers.

ESP8266:

```
AT Version: 0.60.0.0(Jan 29 2016 15:10:17)
SDK version:1.5.2(7eee54f4)
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd
```

If I do not send "Content-Encoding: gzip", then the gzipped content is served, but shown as garbled text offcourse. If I do send the gzip header, then after the headers, the ESP returns an error "link is not valid". And it is not able to send the contents.

Anyone knows what is the issue here?

There is lot of code, and Most of it is working. Here are the relevant parts related to this issue.

In the loop, I check if there is client available. If there is, then I get the headers, get the file name, and based on the file name and extension serve the headers and the content.

Code for sending header:

```
bool sendHeader(uint8_t mux_id,String header){
  byte plain[header.length()];
  header.getBytes(plain, header.length()+1);
  return (wifi.send(mux_id, plain, header.length()+1));
}

void code200(uint8_t mux_id, char* filename) {

  sendHeader(mux_id,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
  sendHeader(mux_id, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n");
  sendHeader(mux_id,"Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
  if (strstr(filename, "test.htm") != 0 ) {
    //No gzip header
  }
  else if ((strstr(filename, ".htm") != 0 || strstr(filename, ".css") != 0) && strstr(filename, "index") == 0) {
    sendHeader(mux_id,"Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n");
  }
  sendHeader(mux_id,"Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n");
  sendHeader(mux_id,"Connection: close\r\n");
  sendHeader(mux_id,"\r\n\r\n");

}
```

Code for sending html content.

```
code200(mux_id, filename);// See above.
webFile = SD.open(filename);
if (webFile) {
  byte buff[512];
  uint32_t c;
  while (true) {
    int c = webFile.read((char*)buff, 512);
    if (!c)
      break;
      wifi.send(mux_id, buff,c );
  }
  webFile.close();
}
break;
```

Comment: The content-encoding header is about how the content is encoded by the server for sending to the client. The content encoding using gzip is (usually?) done by the server reading the (non-gzipped) html file, gzippng it dynamically, sending the gzipped version to the client, and the client un-gzipping. I'd get it serving the html file correctly then worry about gzipping or not. Do you have a desperate need for it to be gzipped on disk?

Comment: @barny yes, there is a desperate need for gzipping. Plus, I have this same method working on arduino+ethernet. as well as on ESP8266 as a standalone unit with SPIFFs. So I have gotten it to work before. But this library uses AT commands,  and ESP is on hardware serial with Due board. it just does not make sense why it returns an error only when content encoding header is added.

Comment: I doubt the header by itself is the problem. Show us your code.

Comment: Which send function are you using?  Did you adjust the length to compensate for the new header?

Comment: @gre_gor I have updated the question with code. I can see the headers come up correctly on google dev tools. So, I guess, the length part is being handled correctly.

Comment: @leetibbett updated with code. I believe the length is handled correctly.

Comment: You have two content-encoding headers, and you have too many \r\n's. There should only be two \r\n's after the headers, not three, to make a single blank line after the last header.  Maybe the client is disconnecting before the data, because you also have a Connection: Close. Adding a content-length header and removing the extra \r\n should help keep it open until the file is sent.  Also, why are you sending `header.length()+1` bytes instead of header.length() for all your headers?  That might also be causing some confusion on the client side.

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) is the HTTP response info

Comment: @leetibbett you are right. It was some extra \r\n that was confusing the browser. Thanks very much.